# Installing gmock on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I've been struggling with installing gmock on Ubuntu for a while now and I'm therefore turning to you since I'm pretty sure it should not be hard and that I'm just missing something essential.

I have managed to install gtest previously but can't remember how unfortunately but gtest is working on the machine that I want to install gmock on.

I've tried installing via
`sudo apt-get install -y googletest`
and
`sudo apt-get install -y google-mock`

This seems to get the trick done and I can compile tests that include `<gmock/gmock.h>` but when i try to link i get the error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmock`

I've tried installing as suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/Cartexius/4c437c084d6e388288201aadf9c8cdd5) but at the step that says `sudo cmake ..` I get the warning:
`CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:54 (project): VERSION keyword not followed by a value or was followed by a value that expanded to nothing.` and no make file seems to be generated.

I've tried downloading the [source](https://github.com/google/googletest) and following the instructions in the Readme.md in the googletest folder but when I try to run the cmake file in the folder i get the error `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:129 (set_target_properties): set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.`

And at this point I'm kinda stumped. The annoying thing is that I have managed to install both googletest and googlemock on a OsX machine a few years ago.

So my question is basically if anyone has updated instructions on best practices on how to install gtest and gmock on Ubuntu? Since I'm using make and not cmake for my project I think I'm more interested in installing gtest and gmock stand alone rather than as part of an existing cmake project. I must add that I'm quite new to both Ubuntu and installations from source.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmock` have you updated `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

google-mock provides only sources, you have to build it and install manually or install package libgmock-dev if available.